# No space on device while gzipping

Tags: python, gzip

I'm using [django-bakery](https://django-bakery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) trying to gzip a large file which is about 1MB in size.

However, it's failing with the error:

```
[2021-11-08 09:59:37] myapp.views DEBUG Target path: /project/build/index.html
[2021-11-08 09:59:37] bakery.views.base DEBUG Gzipping to osfs:////project/build/index.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fs/osfs.py", line 646, in open
    **options
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: b'/project/build/index.html'
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 20. I've encountered this error before, and I'm aware of the [various reasons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919748/no-space-left-on-device-even-though-there-is) that can cause it, and the numerous ways to diagnose the root cause, but so far I'm not seeing any obvious reason.

Running `df -H` shows I have over 200GB of free disk space.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             17G     0   17G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.4G  877k  3.4G   1% /run
/dev/md1        977G  684G  244G  74% /
tmpfs            17G  291k   17G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            17G     0   17G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Running `sudo find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n` does show my `build` directory has a massive number of inodes.

```
        ...
   4414 .git
  38208 .env
 660615 media
16699756 build
```

However, `df -i` shows my disk still has plenty of inodes left:

```
Filesystem       Inodes    IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            4110382      457  4109925    1% /dev
tmpfs           4116299      726  4115573    1% /run
/dev/md1       60563456 18135948 42427508   30% /
tmpfs           4116299       24  4116275    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           4116299        6  4116293    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4116299       18  4116281    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           4116299       11  4116288    1% /run/user/1000
```

When I run the process, I notice it appears to run out of memory. I have 32GB, about half of which is free, and once it consumes all of that, that's when the process reports the lack of storage.

The full traceback goes to:

```
  File "/project/myapp/views.py", line 238, in build_queryset
    self.build_object(o)
  File "/project/myapp/views.py", line 261, in build_object
    self.build_file(target_path, self.get_content())
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bakery/views/base.py", line 68, in build_file
    self.gzip_file(path, html)
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bakery/views/base.py", line 123, in gzip_file
    with self.fs.open(smart_text(target_path), 'wb') as outfile:
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fs/osfs.py", line 646, in open
    **options
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fs/error_tools.py", line 90, in __exit__
    reraise(fserror, fserror(self._path, exc=exc_value), traceback)
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fs/osfs.py", line 646, in open
```

and if I lookup bakery's code for `gzip_file()` I see:

```
# Write GZIP data to an in-memory buffer
data_buffer = six.BytesIO()
kwargs = dict(
    filename=path.basename(target_path),
    mode='wb',
    fileobj=data_buffer
)
if float(sys.version[:3]) >= 2.7:
    kwargs['mtime'] = 0
with gzip.GzipFile(**kwargs) as f:
    f.write(six.binary_type(html))

# Write that buffer out to the filesystem
with self.fs.open(smart_text(target_path), 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(data_buffer.getvalue())
    outfile.close()
```

So it looks like this is error is happening because it's designed to write the gzip data to an in-memory buffer. However, what I don't understand is why it's failing on the line that writes that buffer to disk and not `f.write(six.binary_type(html))` that writes to that in-memory buffer.

Why isn't it failing during the buffer write?

Obviously, a fix for this would be to override this code to skip the in-memory buffer and write directly to disk. That would make smaller writes much slower, but that might just be the cost of doing business.

Are there better solutions? Is there any way to direct Gzip to failover to disk or even swapping instead of raising an exception when it runs out of memory?

Comment: Why do you think the problem has anything to do with the in-memory buffer? It's failing on the line after `# Write that buffer out to the filesystem` which opens the real file.

Comment: @Barmar Two reasons. One, I monitor memory usage while it's running, and the error happens exactly when memory reaches 100% use. Second, I believe the GzipFile call is lazy, and the actual gzipping isn't happening until the outfile.write() line is called, which is in-turn calling the GzipFile's getvalue() method.

Comment: That's not how exceptions work in Python. If the error doesn't happen until `outfile.write()`, it wouldn't say that it's happening on `self.fs.open()`.

Comment: @Barmar Please re-read my comment. I don't think you understood what I wrote. You're actually agreeing with me.